# rounding a number in ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to round this figure to the nearest whole number. I am generating an xml based on an excel file, and would like to round the figure.

Here is my code:

```
  xml.POS110 “wert”: “#{row[18]}”
```

I have tried:

```
  xml.POS110 “wert”: “#{row[18]}”.round(0)
```

Comment: `xml.POS110 "wert": "#{row[18].to_f.round}"`.

Comment: _"I would like to round this figure"_ – which figure? What's your input and your expected output?

Comment: I didnt think it was necessary and believed nearest whole number would be clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Move the round inside the quotes.  Before, you were just trying to round a string.  Also the default argument for round is `0` so you don't need to specify it (but you can if you really want to).

`“#{row[18].round(0)}"`

Comment: This assumes `row[18]` is a `Numeric` already I would recommend casting (as suggested by @mudasobwa in the comment above) just in case it is not